# How to set wizard images in NSIS through CMake/CPack?

Tags: cmake, nsis, cpack

I see that there is no CPACK_xxx variable for changing the wizard image(s) in NSIS (like CPACK_PACKAGE_ICON).
So I copied the NSIS.template.in and modified it. I could do something like:

!define MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP "C:\work\project\img\wizardInstall.bmp"
!define MUI_UNWELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP "C:\work\project\img\wizardUninstall.bmp"

and it will work. However, the source code goes in a repository where many developers colaborate, and it's not really good idea to keep absolute paths there.
I tried to find some way to get my source path, and somehow create the image path from that one, but to no avail.

So, if someone knows how can i set the wizard images in NSIS, or pass the source dir (and create the path from it) to my template file, please let me know.

Comment: You can try to modify your `NSIS.template.in` file while running `cmake` using [file](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:file) command. For example: `file(APPEND NSIS.template.in !define FILEID ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/file !define)`

Comment: I could modify the file this way.. or even better, copy it and then append to the copy. However, then the defines will end-up at the bottom of the script resulting in something like: MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP is already defined (even though i have taken out the definition of it)... Although even if it didn't result in a preprocessing error, it still comes after the !insertmacro for MUI.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already customizing the NSIS.template.in file, and it is a template presumably configured with the CONFIGURE_FILE() command, why not put the following in to your NSIS.template.in:

```
!define MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP "@MY_CPACK_MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP@"
!define MUI_UNWELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP "@MY_CPACK_MUI_UNWELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP@"
```

Then, in your CMakeLists.txt file where you set your other CPACK variables, add something like:

```
SET(MY_CPACK_MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)/path/to/wizardInstall.bmp")
SET(MY_CPACK_MUI_UNWELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)/path/to/wizardUninstall.bmp")
```

Comment: Thanks. But it seems these variables must have only "CPACK" prefix. Otherwise CPack ignores them and they would have an empty value in nsi.

Comment: the path is not defined correctly, see: http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-June/022085.html

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to compile whole NSIS to use/change these images.

They are present on every machine which has NSIS installed in *${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Wizard\win.bmp*

Use `!define MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP bmp_file` in your .nsi script to change them.