# How to set an Icon in NSIS install (CMake)

Tags: cmake, nsis, bmp, cpack

The documentation for `CPACK_PACKAGE_ICON` is very limited on cmake [wiki page](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cpack/PackageGenerators#nsis).

The following is not working for me (as [per](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7746353/136285)):

```
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_ICON  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/images/MyIcon.bmp")
include(CPack)
```

It leads to:

```
File: "C:/proj/my_library/images/MyIcon.bmp" -> no files found.
Usage: File [/nonfatal] [/a] ([/r] [/x filespec [...]] filespec [...] |
   /oname=outfile one_file_only)
Error in macro MUI_HEADERIMAGE_INIT on macroline 24
Error in macro MUI_GUIINIT on macroline 3
Error in macro MUI_FUNCTION_GUIINIT on macroline 4
Error in macro MUI_INSERT on macroline 11
Error in macro MUI_LANGUAGE on macroline 7
Error in script "C:/proj/bin-win/_CPack_Packages/win32/NSIS/project.nsi" on line 574 -- aborting creation process
```

So how does one actually set a working icon during the install process of a NSIS installer ? Also what format is actually needed for the icon ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some trial-and-error I finally found out two tricks required:

The syntax is actually:

```
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_ICON  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/images\\\\MyIcon.bmp")
```

And the BMP file is restricted to an older format, which is not the default for [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#linux). Eg:

```
$ file MyIcon.bmp
MyIcon.bmp: PC bitmap, Windows 98/2000 and newer format, 128 x 128 x 24
```

what is needed is this:

```
$ convert MyIcon.bmp BMP3:MyIcon2.bmp
$ file MyIcon2.bmp
MyIcon2.bmp: PC bitmap, Windows 3.x format, 128 x 128 x 24
```

The first representation (`Windows 98/2000 and newer format`) did not work for me.

Comment: Isn't it [150x57 in size](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI/Readme.html) (under MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP_RTL if you expand Interface settings, Page header)?

Comment: This was haunting me, now after 6 years, you still have to generate images in BPM Windows 3.x format which few tools seem to support.

Comment: I think this is due to the NSIS installer, I think PNG support or something should be added to NSIS. Related issue: https://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/feature-requests/559/

Answer (score 0):

For me that command in CMakeLists.txt works fine:

`set(CPACK_NSIS_MUI_ICON "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/images\\\\icon.ico")`

I found it here https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CPackNSIS.html